# Unit testing the modal component inside Blazored Modal

Tags: blazor, bunit, blazored

Been trying to unit test the component rendered inside Blazored Modal. I can of course test the code around it by mocking `IModalService` but if I want to test the modal component itself, I run into problems. And they stem from calls to `BlazoredModalInstance`, like to `BlazoredModalInstance.CloseAsync(ModalResult)`.

I would have liked to mock it but since it doesn't implement any interface, I can't. I tried to create a new `BlazoredModal` component, but it takes the `BlazoredModalInstance` as a private CascadingParameter which I cannot provide.

I have also tried rendering the `BlazoredModalInstance` with bUnit, giving it some `ModalOptions`, and passing the instance to my modal component, but calls to it lead to crashes (null reference).

Is this somehow possible to achieve? Is there a way to provide cascading parameters without the parameters.Add(...) way?

Comment: Try taking a look at BlazoredModel's own tests, they might have the solution: https://github.com/Blazored/Modal/blob/main/tests/src/Blazored.Modal.Tests/DisplayTests.cs

Comment: @EgilHansen Yes I did that also, but they look like: `var cut = RenderComponent<BlazoredModal>(CascadingValue(modalService));`. I can't say i have seen that CascadingValue-method anywhere...

Comment: It's an old style of passing parameters that is not encourage any more. Check out the docs for how to do it today: https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/passing-parameters-to-components.html#cascading-parameters-and-cascading-values

Comment: @EgilHansen This will not work since the cascading parameter is private... :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531809/how-to-open-a-blazored-modal-with-bunit/68534950#68534950

Comment: @EgilHansen I read that as well. And like you say there, I do test that the modal is invoked, and the response from it by mocking IModalService. But that doesn't actually touch the modal component itself at all. And if I want to test the component inside the modal, I get the problem with no BlazoredModalInstance...